# Error when sending transaction to get my Ledger Nano with Galleon

Tags: ledger

Please help. I am trying to send transaction to get my Ledger Nano with Galleon and I receive this error message: `proto.004-Pt24m4xi.implicit.empty_implicit_contract`

I followed all the gas limit parameters, etc. exactly, but I still get this same error.

Comment: can you please precise the exact parameters you used. thanks